# Inline member initializer containing pointer to member

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initializer, pointer-to-member

At work, I'm experimenting a bit to bring some reflection into our codebase. Basically what I want to achieve, is to capture a pointer to data-member inside the type of the data-member's initializer:

```cpp
template<class Class, int Class::*dataMember>
struct Reflect
{
  operator int() {return 0;}
};

class Foo
{
public:
  int bar = Reflect<Foo, &Foo::bar>{};
};
```

Although clang 3.4.1 (http://gcc.godbolt.org/) and Intel C++ XE 14.0 are able to compile this piece of code, when using MSVC12 I get the following error message:

> error C2065: 'bar' : undeclared identifier
>
> error C2975: 'dataMember' : invalid template argument for 'Reflect', expected compile-time constant expression

Furthermore, gcc 4.9.2 also seems to have trouble with it: http://ideone.com/ZUVOMO.

**So my questions are:**

1. Is the above piece of code valid C++11?
2. If yes, are there any work arounds for the failing compilers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What VC++ complains about is certainly not a problem; [basic.scope.pdecl]/1,6:

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete
>   declarator (Clause 8) **and before its initializer** (if any), except as
>   noted below.[…]
>
> **After the point of declaration of a class member, the member name can
>   be looked up in the scope of its class.**

This implies that the name lookup is fine. However, as pointed out by @hvd in the comments, there are certain ambiguities in the grammar of such constructs.
Presumably GCC parses the above line until the comma:

```
int bar = Reflect<Foo,
// at this point Reflect < Foo can be a perfectly fine relational-expression.
// stuff after the comma could be a declarator for a second member.
```

And bails out once the rest is encountered.

---

A workaround that makes GCC happy is

```
    int bar = decltype( Reflect<Foo, &Foo::bar>{} )();
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25f78764225465e5). This does not help with VC++ though, which apparently confuses the point of declaration as indicated by the error message.
Thus moving the initializer into a constructor will work:

```
int bar;

Foo() : bar( Reflect<Foo, &Foo::bar>{} ) {}
// (also works for GCC)
```

... while providing an initializer at the declaration of `bar` cannot. [**Demo #2**](http://rextester.com/GBOY65984) on rextester.

Comment: It's an unresolved language issue, IIRC. It's unclear when the comma separates template arguments, and when it separates two members. `int a=b<c,d=e>::f;` could either declare member `a` and initialise it to `b<c,d=e>::f`, or could declare member `a` initialised to `b<c`, and member `d` initialised to `e>::f`. It's complicated by the fact that NSDMIs may refer to not-yet-declared members of the class.

Comment: @hvd I assumed that the grammar covered this unambiguously. Good point. Can you find the DR associated with this?

Comment: For the very related problem with default arguments for functions, there's [#325](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#325). Maybe that's what I was remembering, and maybe there isn't a separate issue for NSDMIs.

Comment: @hvd I'm fairly sure that `d=e` cannot be a valid template argument. However, this is a grammatical issue that starts in the parser, isn't it?`

Comment: An overloaded assignment operator may be declared `constexpr`, so assignments can occur inside template arguments.

Comment: @hvd I can't [get it to work.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e236e8f365cfb3bf)

Comment: @hvd I'm pretty sure that `a=b` is gramatically unable to be passed as a template-argument. If it is to designate some object, it must be an *id-expression*, or … - you know the rules in [temp.arg.nontype]/(1.3)

Comment: `constexpr struct S { constexpr int operator=(S) const { return 1; } } a{}, b{}; template <int> void f() { } int main() { f<a=b>(); }` It doesn't designate an object, so those rules don't apply.

Comment: Actually, that is a syntax error and rejected as such by clang. It's a bug that it's accepted by GCC. `f<(a=b)>();` would be valid. The production *template-argument: constant-expression* grammatically simply doesn't allow a top-level assignment operator. In that case, perhaps there isn't any possibility for ambiguities.

Comment: @hvd Is (a=b) a conditional-expression then?

Comment: @hvd Apparently that would be correct: (a=b) is a primary-expression of the form ( *expression* ), where expression can be an *assignment-expression*.

Comment: Yes, a conditional-expression can be a primary-expression, and a primary-expression can be a parenthesised expression (which allows assignment).